# How to install Pop Theme on Ubuntu 16.04 - E: Unable to locate package pop-theme

Tags: 16.04, gnome, themes, gnome-shell

I'm trying to install Pop-theme, it's a great looking theme, and I really want to install it. The [Github Repo](https://github.com/pop-os/icon-theme) outlines the steps I've already tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:system76/pop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pop-theme
```

I get **E: Unable to locate package pop-theme**

```
~$ sudo apt install pop-theme
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pop-theme
```

Manual installation also gives the same issue. I also know its not a typo problem.

```
$ sudo apt install libsass0 sassc inkscape optipng libglib2.0-dev-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sassc
E: Unable to locate package libglib2.0-dev-bin
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libglib2.0-dev-bin'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libglib2.0-dev-bin'
```

The Repo says **Supported Desktop Environments**

```
* GNOME-Shell     >= 3.18.3
* GNOME-Flashback >= 3.18.2
* Budgie-Desktop  >= 10.2.7...
```

I have GNOME Shell 3.18.5, running Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04.

Comment: It seems the PPA doesn't have a `pop-theme` package for Ubuntu 16.04. Why don't you try the git cloning method mentioned in the GitHub page?

Comment: I wasn't very sure clone the repo so tried .debs from [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/system76-pop-gtk-theme-ubuntu)

Comment: The icons work fine. But the theme doesn't apply well on nautilus. The lack of a dark variant as well make combining Pop icon pack and Arc theme a satisfactory result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download and install a .deb file from [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/04/system76-pop-gtk-theme-ubuntu).