# Ubuntu 'Videos' Application has 'Unknown' in Taskbar when Playing .mp4

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, totem, ubuntu-dock

Whenever I open a .mp4 file using the default videos application on Ubuntu 18.04, this obnoxious 'Unknown' icon in the taskbar pops up that I can't get rid of. The description of the window when hovered over is simply 'OpenGL Renderer'

[image: Photo of the icon in question]

Edit: Output of `glxinfo | grep renderer`:

```
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)
```

Edit2: Unfortunately, the suggested duplicates don't really solve my problem. That question seems to deal with having icons that have permanently changed to question marks, even when the icon is dormant in the taskbar. My issue is precisely as follows:

1. All icons in the taskbar or otherwise are as expected. I open a `.mp4` file using `totem` (the `Videos` application)
2. The `.mp4` file is opened and plays without issue in the `Videos` application, and the `Videos` application has the correct icon
3. However, the error-style second icon appears in the taskbar. When hovered, it is simply labeled `Unknown`. When right-clicked, it is labeled `OpenGL Renderer`. I cannot close the 'window' from this icon (which doesn't seem to actually exist anywhere on my screen), but the icon automatically disappears once I close my `.mp4` file.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] the output of `glxinfo | grep renderer` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Similar issue solved here https://askubuntu.com/questions/329673/how-can-i-fix-program-icons-that-appear-as-a-question-mark-in-the-launcher

Comment: From your update its obvious that this is a second, backround process which shouldn't be appearing on the taskbar/dock.

Comment: What plugins are you using in totem? the output of `glxinfo -l | grep version` might also be useful. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0):

This is disappointingly common on Ubuntu, possibly naming mismatches. First try overriding the Suru Icon Pack (default for Ubuntu 18).

**Install it**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install suru-icon-theme
```

**Apply it**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme Suru
```

On Unity you can use the Tweak tool

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

In case you have any issues installing Suru from the repo's, try downloading it through [this article](https://www.ubuntupit.com/install-ubuntu-touch-suru-icon-theme-ubuntu-derivatives/).

Another solution is to switch to a new icon pack, I've had far less occurrences since using the [Pop Icon Pack](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1051235/how-to-install-pop-theme-on-ubuntu-16-04-e-unable-to-locate-package-pop-theme/1051244#1051244).

Comment: I tried both suggestions, and unfortunately the same icon still pops up regardless of the icon pack. This issue I think is also slightly different from the question mark desktop icons, as I don't even understand why an icon would pop up for `OpenGL Renderer` when I open a `.mp4` file. I may just change to a different videos application besides totem. Unfortunately VLC has been proving to have its own problems, though.

Comment: Hmmm, could be a 18.04 issue. Lets see if theres a better way.